# Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this object.

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "id":"7",
      "nombre":"127",
      "ciudad":"1"
   },
   "1":{  
      "id":"8",
      "nombre":"cll 155",
      "ciudad":"1"
   },
   "2":{  
      "id":"10",
      "nombre":"Cra 30",
      "ciudad":"1"
   },
   "3":{  
      "id":"30",
      "nombre":"Repuestos",
      "ciudad":"1"
   },
   "4":{  
      "id":"6",
      "nombre":"Ibagué",
      "ciudad":"3"
   },
   "5":{  
      "id":"9",
      "nombre":"Villavicencio",
      "ciudad":"2"
   }
}
```

If I use it in a `ng-options` it works perfect and the options are created.

```
<select name="user_dealer" 
 ng-model="formModel.user_dealer" 
 ng-options="dealer.nombre for dealer in concesionarios">
    <option value="" ng-if="!formModel.user_dealer">Concesionario</option>
</select>
```

However when I add a filter:

```
 <select name="user_dealer" 
  ng-model="formModel.user_dealer" 
  ng-options="dealer.nombre for dealer in concesionarios | filter: {ciudad:1}">
 <option value="" ng-if="!formModel.user_dealer">Concesionario</option>
</select>
```

I get this error

> Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received:
>   {"0":{"id":"7","nombre":"
>   127","ciudad":"1"},"1":{"id":"8","nombre":"cll
>   155","ciudad":"1"},"2":{"id":"10","nombre":"Cra
>   30","ciudad":"1"},"3":{"id":"30","nombre":"
>   Repuestos","ciudad":"1"},"4":{"id":"6","nombre":"
>   Ibagué","ciudad":"3"},"5":{"id":"9","nombre":"
>   Villavicencio","ciudad":"2"}}

Comment: take a look at the docs for [notarray](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because ngFilter expects arrays, not objects. You can convert your `concesionarios` object into an array and do the following with your HTML:

```
<select name="user_dealer"
        ng-model="formModel.user_dealer"
        ng-options="dealer as dealer.nombre in concesionarios | filter: {ciudad:1}">
        <option value="" ng-if="!formModel.user_dealer">Concesionario</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Angular's documentation on filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) states:

> Selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array.

The `concesionarios` object is not an array, hence `filter` doesn't work. The `concesionarios` object should look like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"7",
      "nombre":"127",
      "ciudad":"1"
   },
   {  
      "id":"8",
      "nombre":"cll 155",
      "ciudad":"1"
   },
   {  
      "id":"10",
      "nombre":"Cra 30",
      "ciudad":"1"
   },
... // other objects
]
```